# less variable not being picked up via import

Tags: compiler-construction, import, less

I have he following in a primary .less file:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 47.0625em) {
    @import "_grid.less";
    @import "_768up.less";
} 

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 47.0625em) 
and (max-device-width: 64.375em) {
    @import "_768to1030.less";
}
```

There's a variable set in `_grid.less` that is used in both `_768up.less` and `_768to1030.less` but when the import is placed as it is above it throws out an error when compiling.

If I move the `_grid.less` import to sit first in the last media query it doesn't throw out the error but then none of the elements that use the variable in `_768up.less` get styled...

It's a real puzzler.

P.S. I'm using CodeKit for OS X as my compiler.

Comment: Got a down vote for this but no explanation as to why?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can now couple `@import` statement and media queries in less like that:

```
@import "responsive/mobile" only screen and (min-width: 47.0625em) {
    /* CSS GETS IMPORTED INTO A MEDIA QUERY */
}
```

I stumbled over this [**bug report**](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/122) for less.js... The issue is closed in 1.4, but there are still compilers that are ports (dotless) or use an older version. Maybe an update if available would solve the issue.

You should try using less.js directly and see if the error occures there. If not, then it's the CodeKit compiler version breaking things.

Comment: Didn't know about the `@import` statement, thanks. Will look into CodeKit t see if it's that.

Comment: I am still running across this issue with the ported dotLESS compiler. Has anyone been able to group the (partial) less files together in a less media query statement?

Answer (score 0):

### Variable Scope is Your Issue

If you have a variable used in both, then that variable must be set "outside" the `@media` blocks in order for them both to access it. So you need to do this:

```
@import "_grid.less";

@media only screen and (min-width: 47.0625em) {
    @import "_768up.less";
} 

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 47.0625em) 
and (max-device-width: 64.375em) {
    @import "_768to1030.less";
}
```

Or you need to separate out those common variables to another file and then do this:

```
@import "_commonVariables.less";

@media only screen and (min-width: 47.0625em) {
    @import "_grid.less";
    @import "_768up.less";
} 

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 47.0625em) 
and (max-device-width: 64.375em) {
    @import "_768to1030.less";
}
```

Or you need to repeat yourself to get the variable in scope for both `@media` blocks:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 47.0625em) {
    @import "_grid.less";
    @import "_768up.less";
} 

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 47.0625em) 
and (max-device-width: 64.375em) {
    @import "_grid.less";
    @import "_768to1030.less";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want to do this as it would import the `_grid.less` file into my mobile css as well as larger screens which means I'd have to overwrite some of the styles.

Comment: Then some repetition is going to be necessary, as you need to get that variable somehow in scope to the `@media`. If the first two solutions do not work because of overwriting that would be needed, then you will have to repeat the `_grid.less` call inside each `@media` that needs the code. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I tried that before posting but it was still throwing out n error. I think it's more to do with my compiler (CodeKit). In the end, I just got rid of the `_grid.less` import and added it to `_768up.less`